# Reading resource file Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to access `High_Scores.txt` file stored in folder `Resources`.

My project tree looks like this:

[image: Project Tree]

I am using the code shown below to access the file. Checked this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar) but the solutions are not working in my case.

```
File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/Resources/High_Scores.txt").getFile());
```

But I keep on getting `NULLPointerException`. I do not understand this exception clearly in this context. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

If I alter the code to this:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Resources/High_Scores.txt").getFile());
```

I get `FILENOTFOUNDException`.

Comment: @Tunaki This question is follow up to that question. Can't you see I have tried that question's answer but still face an issue.

Comment: You cannot access a resource that is inside a JAR as a `File` like you're trying here, this simply can't work. You have to use an `InputStream`, as shown in the linked question.

Comment: Thank you. Now you should have answered this question like that instead of marking duplicate -.-

Comment: Ah I could have indeed, but there's no point in duplicating content. It is preferable to refer to a question instead of repeating the same things.

Answer (score 0):

For reading file you can use `InputStream` instead of new `File()` like this (Let assume you are calling to read file From `Board` class)

```
InputStream stream = Board.class.getResourceAsStream("/Resources/high.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append(line);
    }
    System.out.println(out.toString());   //Prints the string content read from input stream
    reader.close();
```

or you can use `ClassLoader` Object

```
File file = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/Resources/high.txt").getFile());
```

if specific directories contain folder

```
File file = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/Resources/high.txt").toURI());
```

Comment: I want to use the `File` method. Surely there will be a way to read/write file using file. I want to write also so this inputstream method won't work for me.

Comment: @MohsinAnees look at the update answer

Comment: NULLPointerException still. Is @Tunaki saying correct that using file inside JAR is not possible?

Comment: @MohsinAnees Ofcourse use InputStream instead